# Block element displaying as Inline (positioned absolute, left)

Tags: html, css

I have a container and an inner block-level element ([fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/wjLc2/1/)):

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <span>Something is written here</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    position:relative;
    width:300px;
    height:20px;
    background:blue;
}

#container span {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    left:250px;
    background:green;
    color:white;
}
```

Why is `#container span` words are splitted by line, instead of being one line? Please note, that if I change the position from `left` to negative right - `right:-20px;` - the message is no longer splitted. Why? I can't use right since my messages regardless of length should start from the same point on the right side of container block. The message won't also be splitted if I specify `width`, but I can't do that either since I don't know in advance the length of the message

Comment: In your fiddle, the span is inline-block, but above you have it as block level.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's inline-block or block, anyways I made it block in my jsFiddler

Comment: I'm not say that as an answer, just an observation of the discrepancy between the code in your question and the code in your fiddle.

Comment: `white-space: nowrap;` if you don’t want it to wrap.

Comment: Because you if you move that block over 250px in a 300px container it will only be 50px wide. The words are going to break when the reach the end of that 50px block.

Comment: Why does the text wrap? Because it always does by default. If you put text inside a plain `<div>` it will wrap if there's not enough space. Why did you expect it to not wrap here?

Comment: @Jon, it seems like I've never come across this behavior so I wasn't aware of it :). Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid wrapping, use

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

From [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space#Values):

> **nowrap**
>      Collapses whitespace as for normal, but suppresses line breaks (text wrapping) within text.

---

The problem was that if you set a too large `left` value, you are pushing the element to the right from the left, and its right side will attempt to remain inside `#container`, so there's wrapping.

If you use `right: -20px` there's no wrapping because you are pulling the element to the right from the right, so there's no point in trying to make the right side remain inside.

The above is just the idea behind the behavior, which is defined specifically in [this section of the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width):

> 'width' and 'right' are 'auto' and 'left' is not 'auto', then the width is shrink-to-fit . Then solve for 'right'

The cause of the wrapping is that "shrink-to-fit".

Comment: Awesome solution! Thanks a lot! Care to explain why `white-space: nowrap;` does the trick?

Comment: Got you! Thanks a lot of the elaboration!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know why it's because you if you move that block over 250px in a 300px container it will only be 50px wide. The words are going to break when the reach the end of that 50px block.

If you move it to the right -20px you will have 320px for the message to fill and it will not wrap in this case.